# PlayonLinux install menu is empty

Tags: 12.04, wine, playonlinux

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

I installed PlayOnLinux by adding their repository to Software Sources. My PlayOnLinux version is 4.1.2

When I try to install a program the install menu is totally empty.[image]

So, I tried running PlayonLinux from terminal and this the output I got.

`Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/share/playonlinux/python/install.py", line 315, in search

    self.apps = codecs.open(Variables.playonlinux_rep+"/configurations/listes  /search",'r',"utf-8")

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 881, in open

    file = builtin.open(filename, mode, buffering)

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/karthik/.PlayOnLinux//configurations/listes/search'

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/share/playonlinux/python/install.py", line 434, in AddApps

    self.apps = codecs.open(Variables.playonlinux_rep+"/configurations/listes/4",'r',"utf-8")

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 881, in open

    file = builtin.open(filename, mode, buffering)

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/karthik/.PlayOnLinux//configurations/listes/4'`

I searched the playonlinux forums and found a [discussion](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/topic-7919-PlayOnLinux_website_is_unavailable.html) which matched the problem. Eventhough, I followed the instructions there, the problem did not get solved.

Also, I am behind an authenticated proxy server. I filled the proxy server details in the PlayonLinux preferences.

I would really like get PlayonLinux working. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This *sounds like a bug*.  But also, you've got a problem there, since its in the PlayOnLinux software from their repository, the Ubuntu bugs team cant fix it.  Also, verify that `/home/karthik/.PlayOnLinux//configurations/listes/4` is a valid path in your system, its erroring on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I uninstalled the program from PlayOnLinux repo and installed the program from the official repo. The program in the official repo seems to be working properly.